# "Object is undefined" error, when trying to rotate object in three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, error-handling, three.js, undefined

"Object is undefined" error, when trying to rotate object in three.js. snippet of code:

```
var object;

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
    object.rotation.x += 0.1;
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
}
```

Comment: Well, from the code you've posted, you never assign to it, so yes, it would be `undefined`, what else could it be...?

Comment: could you explain further what you mean, eg. how to assign. sorry im a noob.

Comment: @Nuser0101 How do you set the value of the `object` variable? Please, read about [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the problem, I'm only going to go over the problem code:

```
var object; // undefined
object.rotation.x += 0.1; //trying to access a key inside an undefined
```

Declaring `object` in the global scope is fine, but you're only declaring it and have not assigned it to a value. This means you're trying to find a key inside a variable that is `undefined`.

```
var object = {};
object.rotation.x += 0.1; // object.rotation is undefined
```

Still not good enough. The variable `object` does not a possess a key named `rotation`. It is undefined. You will be trying to key into a key that does not exist. I'm not sure of your use case, but for this exact scenario, assigning `object` as an object with all the keys you need manually will fix this `undefined` issue you're having.

```
var object = {
    rotation: {
        x: 0
    }
};
object.rotation.x += 0.1;
```